# Sequence extension that works on Arrays, Sets and Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, sequence

I'm learning Swift with Paul Hudson's 100 days of Swift. In one of his extension lessons, I have found a notion that more advanced developers could write a `Sequence` extension that would service Arrays, Sets and Dictionaries:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/understanding-swift/when-are-protocol-extensions-useful-in-swift

I have given this a shot but:

1. I don't know how to create a variable that could change its type (wonder if that's even possible at all)
2. I don't know how to create a sequence that would service dictionaries too, since their syntax for `allSatisfy` is a bit different

Would you be so kind and give me a hand here? :)

The code:

```
extension Sequence {
        
        var isAllEven:Bool {
            numbers.allSatisfy { $0.isMultiple(of:2)}
        }
}

let numbers = Set([4, 8, 15, 16])
print(numbers.isAllEven)
```

I can change numbers to be both Array and Set but as soon as I understood what Paul said, there is a possibility to create an extension that could service all 3 in one passage of code without having to change the variables content.

Comment: A dictionary is a sequence of key value pairs. Do you want to check that all the keys are even, or all the values are even, or both?

Comment: Only the values, @Sweeper

Comment: @Swantewit Note that you are applying allSatisfy method to the numbers object instead of the sequence itself

Comment: You did not yet actually understand what Paul said. He was specifically talking about `allSatisfy` and other similarly-generalized members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `isMultiple(of:)` belongs to all integer types a generic version **must** be constrained to `BinaryInteger`

```
extension Sequence where Element : BinaryInteger {
    var isAllEven : Bool {
        allSatisfy {$0.isMultiple(of: 2)}
    }
}
```

But this cannot cover `Dictionary`, because although `Dictionary` conforms to `Sequence` the `Element` type is different.

You could write a second extension of `Sequence` which matches the `Dictionary` *tuple type*

```
extension Sequence where Element == (key:String, value:Int) {
    var isAllEven : Bool {
        allSatisfy {$0.value.isMultiple(of:2)}
    }
}
```

but this considers only `String` keys and `Int` values

A more generic way is to extend `Dictionary`  directly

```
extension Dictionary where Value : BinaryInteger {
    var isAllEven : Bool {
        allSatisfy {$0.value.isMultiple(of: 2)}
    }
}
```